# How do I display multiple badge-count in lightning-vertical-navigation?

Tags: lightning-web-components, count, navigation-menu

I need to do something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if `lightning-vertical-navigation-item-badge` is used here, because I don't know how to add a second `badge-count`. That's what I have at the moment. Any thoughts and advice are welcome. I don't mind using something else, either.

```
<div style="width: 320px;">
    <lightning-vertical-navigation onselect={handleSelectMonth} selected-item={selectedMonth}>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Months">
            <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-badge label="January" name="1" badge-count={badgeCountJanuary}></lightning-vertical-navigation-item-badge>
            ...
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
lightning-vertical-navigation-item-badge
```

only seems to support 1 column / badge, you can easily crate a vertical navigation component using standard HTML/CSS and/or add slds for styling purposes

lightning namespaced components are restricted to their available attributes and [shadow dom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

when implementing custom use cases, consider using [SLDS Blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/overview/) you can start using the available base code provided in the blueprints for [vertical navigation](http://Vertical%20Navigation) and further tweak the code to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way,:

```
    <table >    
    <thead style='display:none;'>     
      <tr > 
          <td  width="33px" >            
          </td>                 
          <td  width="33px">                   
          </td>             
          <td  width="33px">              
          </td>            
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr >
        <td>
          {monthName}
        </td>
        <td>
          <template if:true={monthlyExpenseSpentAmount}>        
            <span class="slds-badge"><lightning-formatted-number value={monthlyExpenseSpentAmount} format-style="decimal" minimum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number></span> 
          </template>
        </td>
        <td>
        <template if:true={monthlyExpenseSpentAmount}> 
          <span class="slds-badge" if:true={monExIncome}><lightning-formatted-number value={monExIncome} format-style="decimal" minimum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number></span> 
        </template>
        <template if:false={monthlyExpenseSpentAmount}>    
          <span class="slds-badge " if:true={monExIncome}><lightning-formatted-number value={monExIncome} format-style="decimal" minimum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number></span>
        </template>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```